# Lookup Hbase Tbl from UDF (Beeline , Hbase,Delegation Tokens)

Tags: hive, hbase, kerberos, cloudera-cdh, apache-sentry

I have a requirement to write Custom UDF for data lookup  from Hbase Table .

NOTE : I have done Unit Testing with HIVE . It seems to be working .

But when I use the same UDF Beeline, Its failed . By default Cloudera restricts impersonation and allows only hive user for running queries in Beeline. On Job startup , YarnChild is setting the following delegations tokens.

I want to add token (Kind : **HBASE_AUTH_TOKEN** ) for dealing with Hbase.

```
Kind: mapreduce.job
Kind: HDFS_DELEGATION_TOKEN 
Kind: kms-dt
```

I researched and found out how HbaseStorageHandler is using Delegation Token ( i.e HBASE_AUTH_TOKEN ) for Hbase . So I used the same set of functions and its not working either .

**Functions from  HbasestorageHandler  (to obtain tokens to Job ) :**

```
private void addHBaseDelegationToken(Configuration conf, JobConf jconf) throws IOException {
        if (User.isHBaseSecurityEnabled(conf)) {
            try {
                logger.info("isHbaseSecurityEnabled :True ");
                User e = User.getCurrent();
                logger.info("isHbaseSecurityEnabled :User ==> " + e.toString());
                Token authToken = getAuthToken(conf, e);
                logger.info("isHbaseSecurityEnabled :AuthToken==> "+authToken.toString());
                Job job = new Job(conf);
                if(authToken == null) {
                    UserGroupInformation ugi = UserGroupInformation.getLoginUser();
                    ugi.setAuthenticationMethod(UserGroupInformation.AuthenticationMethod.KERBEROS);
                    e.obtainAuthTokenForJob(jconf);
  } else {
                    logger.info("authToken is not null"+authToken.toString());
                    job.getCredentials().addToken(authToken.getService(), authToken);
                }

                logger.info("obtained Token /....");
            } catch (InterruptedException var5) {
                throw new IOException("Error while obtaining hbase delegation token", var5);
            }
        }

    }


private static Token<AuthenticationTokenIdentifier> getAuthToken(Configuration conf, User user) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        ZooKeeperWatcher zkw = new ZooKeeperWatcher(conf, "mr-init-credentials", (Abortable) null);

        Token var4;
        try {
            String e = ZKClusterId.readClusterIdZNode(zkw);
            logger.info("====== clusterID : " + e);
            var4 = (new AuthenticationTokenSelector()).selectToken(new Text(e), user.getUGI().getTokens());
             if (var4 == null) {
                logger.info("var4 is null===========================");
            } else {
                logger.info("====== Hbase Token : " + var4.toString());
            }
        } catch (KeeperException var8) {
            throw new IOException(var8);
        } catch (NullPointerException np) {
            return null;
        } finally {
            zkw.close();
        }
        return var4;
 }
```

After calling addHBaseDelegationToken() in configure() of UDF. I am getting the following exception .I am not sure How  I can make hvie user to talk with Hbase as hive.keytab is handled by Cloudera and its secured.

Any Inputs might  be helpful. Thanks !

**Exception StackTrace :**

> 2018-10-11 04:48:07,625 WARN [main] org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException as:hive (auth:SIMPLE) cause:javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed [Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)]
>   2018-10-11 04:48:07,627 WARN [main] org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl: Exception encountered while connecting to the server : javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed [Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)]
>   2018-10-11 04:48:07,628 FATAL [main] org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl: SASL authentication failed. The most likely cause is missing or invalid credentials. Consider 'kinit'.
>   javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed [Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)]
>       at com.sun.security.sasl.gsskerb.GssKrb5Client.evaluateChallenge(GssKrb5Client.java:211)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.security.HBaseSaslRpcClient.saslConnect(HBaseSaslRpcClient.java:181)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection.setupSaslConnection(RpcClientImpl.java:618)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection.access$700(RpcClientImpl.java:163)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection$2.run(RpcClientImpl.java:744)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection$2.run(RpcClientImpl.java:741)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1920)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection.setupIOstreams(RpcClientImpl.java:741)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection.writeRequest(RpcClientImpl.java:907)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection.tracedWriteRequest(RpcClientImpl.java:874)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl.call(RpcClientImpl.java:1246)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient.callBlockingMethod(AbstractRpcClient.java:227)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient$BlockingRpcChannelImplementation.callBlockingMethod(AbstractRpcClient.java:336)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.ClientProtos$ClientService$BlockingStub.execService(ClientProtos.java:34118)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.ProtobufUtil.execService(ProtobufUtil.java:1633)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RegionCoprocessorRpcChannel$1.call(RegionCoprocessorRpcChannel.java:104)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RegionCoprocessorRpcChannel$1.call(RegionCoprocessorRpcChannel.java:94)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller.callWithRetries(RpcRetryingCaller.java:136)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RegionCoprocessorRpcChannel.callExecService(RegionCoprocessorRpcChannel.java:107)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.CoprocessorRpcChannel.callBlockingMethod(CoprocessorRpcChannel.java:73)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.AuthenticationProtos$AuthenticationService$BlockingStub.getAuthenticationToken(AuthenticationProtos.java:4512)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.security.token.TokenUtil.obtainToken(TokenUtil.java:86)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.security.token.TokenUtil$1.run(TokenUtil.java:111)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.security.token.TokenUtil$1.run(TokenUtil.java:108)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1920)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.security.User$SecureHadoopUser.runAs(User.java:340)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.security.token.TokenUtil.obtainToken(TokenUtil.java:108)
>       at com.barclaycardus.hadoop.utils.udfs.HbaseTblLookupUDF.configure(HbaseTblLookupUDF.java:131)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapredContext.setup(MapredContext.java:120)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExprNodeGenericFuncEvaluator.initialize(ExprNodeGenericFuncEvaluator.java:143)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.initEvaluators(Operator.java:954)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.initEvaluatorsAndReturnStruct(Operator.java:980)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SelectOperator.initializeOp(SelectOperator.java:63)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.initialize(Operator.java:385)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.initialize(Operator.java:469)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.initializeChildren(Operator.java:425)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TableScanOperator.initializeOp(TableScanOperator.java:196)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.initialize(Operator.java:385)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator.initializeOp(MapOperator.java:431)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.initialize(Operator.java:385)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecMapper.configure(ExecMapper.java:126)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:106)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:75)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:133)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.configure(MapRunner.java:38)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:106)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:75)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:133)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:455)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:164)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1920)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
>   Caused by: GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)
>       at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5InitCredential.getInstance(Krb5InitCredential.java:147)
>       at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5MechFactory.getCredentialElement(Krb5MechFactory.java:122)
>       at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5MechFactory.getMechanismContext(Krb5MechFactory.java:187)
>       at sun.security.jgss.GSSManagerImpl.getMechanismContext(GSSManagerImpl.java:224)
>       at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.initSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:212)
>       at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.initSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:179)
>       at com.sun.security.sasl.gsskerb.GssKrb5Client.evaluateChallenge(GssKrb5Client.java:192)
>       ... 66 more

Already Tried below options :

https://github.com/apache/oozie/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/apache/oozie/action/hadoop/HbaseCredentials.java

https://github.com/ibm-research-ireland/sparkoscope/blob/master/yarn/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/deploy/yarn/security/HBaseCredentialProvider.scala